# File Upload By form_tag form on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tags, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to make a simple file uploader using tag_form on Rails 3.2.8.
But when I try to submit a image file, I get an error saying


**Error Message (when I try to submit a image file)**

> NoMethodError in CoursesController#attachment
>   undefined method `original_filename' for "2012-03-02 21.53.55.jpg":String

----- BEGIN P.S.(20121216 19:32) -----
or
**Error Message (when I added ":multipart => true" on show.html.erb)**

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in CoursesController#attachment
>   "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

----- END P.S. -----
It seems that the program consider the file as String?
There might be some problem in the view file.
I'd appreciate it if you help me with this problem. Here's my codes.

**app/view/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(attachment_course_path, :action=>'attachment') do %>
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :file %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**app/controller/courses_controller.rb**

```
def attachment
  t = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
  uploaded_io = params[:file]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'upload', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :courses, :only => [ :show ] do
  member do
    post :attachment
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

seems the form is not sending files with request. you need to set :multipart => true in form_tag.

Comment: First, thank you for helping me! I appreciate it.
I added ":multipart=>true" and it looks like this now:
    <%= form_tag(attachment_course_path, :action=>'attachment', :multipart => true) do %>

Now, I get another error.
>Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in CoursesController#attachment
>"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Do you know the solution?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909812/error-ruby-on-rails-encodingundefinedconversionerror-in-coursescontrollerat

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems similar to [RoR upload Undefined encoding conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909812/error-ruby-on-rails-encodingundefinedconversionerror-in-coursescontrollerat)

After setting `:multipart => true` in `form_tag` you need to open the file in binary mode (`'wb'` instead of `'w`'):

**app/controller/courses_controller.rb**

```
...
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'upload', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
...
```