# Error, Ruby on Rails: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in CoursesController#attachment "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to make a simple file uploader using tag_form on Rails 3.2.8.
But when I try to submit a image file, I get an error saying


**Error Message (when I try to submit a image file)**

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in CoursesController#attachment
>   "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I'd appreciate it if you help me with this problem.
Here's my codes.

**app/view/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(attachment_course_path, :action=>'attachment', :multipart => true) do %>
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :file %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**app/controller/courses_controller.rb**

```
def attachment
  t = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
  uploaded_io = params[:file]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'upload', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :courses, :only => [ :show ] do
  member do
    post :attachment
  end
end
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try to open the file in binary mode (`'wb'` instead of `'w'`):

```
  ...
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'upload', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
```

[Ruby Docs IO Open Mode](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)